# AppleScript for moving completed downloads to other folders

Tags: applescript, file

I'm looking to write a script that will move all file in the downloads folder (once fully downloaded) to different folders on the hard drive and external hard drive. Where can I learn more about how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a folder action like this:

[image]

Or create rules like this in [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the Apple official documentation regarding [Applescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/ScriptingOnOSX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000032-BABEBGCF).

Here are two other tutorials, all obtained through google when I was learning myself.

http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/index.html

http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automation/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript-2/

I found both the above very good.